# How to enable systemd user units in 14.10

Tags: services, systemd

I put a unit under ~/.config/systemd/unit:

```
[Unit]
Description=Test systemd user enabled

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'echo afdasf > /home/joelmo/sysdworking'

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

But I don't think this is beeing run, i see no file sysdworking. Is it possible to enable user units in 14.10?

Answer (score 1):

For me this worked:

```
systemctl --user enable myunit
```

The following command shows if the unit is enabled:

```
systemctl --user status myunit
```

Answer (score -1):

```
systemctl enable unit
```

enables systemd user units

Comment: I get `~ sudo systemctl enable unit`
`Operation failed: No such file or directory`